# Flutter Firebase how to updateData without overwritting the value?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update the data value I have in my Firebase database however, whenever I use the method .updateData(data), it overwrites the existing data to whatever was in that data. I've used FieldValue.increment() but to no avail; it constantly crashes my app (the console says Lost Connection To Device).

What I am hoping to accomplish is to + 1 to the 'Count' field that's all. But as previously stated FieldValue.increment() crashes my app :(

The data is formatted as such:

```
{restaurantA: [{Count: 2, Item Name: Yummy Food, Location: Rowland Heights}]}
```

My code is as below:

```
if (value.data.containsKey(restaurantName)) {
        // Check if item is in here method below
        value.data[restaurantName].forEach((itemElement) {
          if (itemElement['Item Name'] == itemName) {
            wishesDBRef.updateData({
              // Error: This part replaces the existing values to the below
              restaurantName: [
                {
                  'Item Name': itemName,
                  'Count': itemElement['Count'] + 1,
                  'Location': restaurantLocation,
                }
              ]
            });
          } else {
            wishesDBRef.updateData({
              restaurantName: FieldValue.arrayUnion([
                {
                  'Item Name': itemName,
                  'Count': 1,
                  'Location': restaurantLocation,
                }
              ]),
            });
          }
        });
        // Item is not in here add item in here method below
      } else {
        wishesDBRef.updateData({
          restaurantName: [
            {
              'Item Name': itemName,
              'Count': 1,
              'Location': restaurantLocation,
            }
          ]
        });
      }
```

The existing code will change the value from:

```
{restaurantA: [{Count: 2, Item Name: Yummy Food, Location: Rowland Heights}, {Count: 5, Item Name: delicious Food, Location: Rowland Heights}]}
```

To:

```
{restaurantA: [{Count: 3, Item Name: Yummy Food, Location: Rowland Heights}]}
```

What I want:

```
{restaurantA: [{Count: 3, Item Name: Yummy Food, Location: Rowland Heights}, {Count: 5, Item Name: delicious Food, Location: Rowland Heights}]}
```

Not sure how I should do this as I have been trying all kinds of methods.
Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT: Maybe it's in the way of how I referenced my database?

```
void uploadWish(String restaurantName, String itemName,
    String restaurantLocation) async {
       var wishesDBRef =
       await dbReference.collection('Users').document('Wishes');
       await wishesDBRef.get().then((value) {
          // The above if-else statement here
       }
```

Comment: You can use `setData ` instead of `updateData` and have the parameter `merge:true`.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta tried that and that still overwrites the value I had

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add only the specific field and the value you are trying to update when using updateData function.
Also looks like you have a an array that has restaurants and subfiles you need to mention the index of that specific element in the database reference.
In case of having different documents, in restaurantA collection the below code should do the work.

```
if (itemElement['Item Name'] == itemName) {
        wishesDBRef.updateData({
          
          restaurantName: [
            {
              
              'Count': itemElement['Count'] + 1,
              
            }
          ]
        }, merge: true);
      }
```

Do let me know if thats what you were looking for.

Comment: just tried the above method and it changed my value to [{Count: 5}]

Comment: I'm sorry i missed out merge:true;